# Creating Python module from Fortan using CMake and make yields no errors but importing module in Python fails due to undefined symbol

Tags: python, c, cmake, fortran, f2py

I am receiving

```
Python 3.12.0 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Oct  3 2023, 08:43:22) [GCC 12.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/.../myproject/build/foo.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: f2pywrapfoo_
```

when trying to load a Python module created using CMake from Fortran code using `numpy.f2py`.

---

I am following the [official guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/buildtools/cmake.html) for using `numpy.f2py` in CMake. I am using the latest version of NumPy (1.26), CMake 3.22 and the `gfortran` and `gcc` compilers from the Xubuntu 22.04 repos (11.4 and 12.3 respectively).

My Fortran function is even simpler (since I am very new to the language) than the example in the documentation, namely

```
function foo(a) result(b)
    implicit none
    
    real(kind=8), intent(in)    :: a(:,:)
    complex(kind=8)             :: b(size(a,1),size(a,2))
    
    b = exp((0,1)*a)
    
end function foo
```

The part of my CMake that handles the module generation is

```
if(PYTHON_F2PY)
# https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/buildtools/cmake.html
# https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/usage.html
    message("Creating Python module from Fortran code enabled")
    # Example for interfacing with Python using f2py
    # Check if Python with the required version and components is available
    find_package(Python 3.12 REQUIRED
    COMPONENTS Interpreter Development.Module NumPy)

    # Grab the variables from a local Python installation
    # F2PY headers
    execute_process(
    COMMAND "${Python_EXECUTABLE}"
    -c "import numpy.f2py; print(numpy.f2py.get_include())"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE F2PY_INCLUDE_DIR
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
    #message("${F2PY_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    # Print out the discovered paths
    include(CMakePrintHelpers)
    cmake_print_variables(Python_INCLUDE_DIRS)
    cmake_print_variables(F2PY_INCLUDE_DIR)
    cmake_print_variables(Python_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS)

    # Common variables
    set(f2py_module_name "foo")
    set(fortran_src_file "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/foo.f90")
    set(f2py_module_c "${f2py_module_name}module.c")

    # Generate sources
    add_custom_target(
    genpyf
    DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${f2py_module_c}"
    )
    add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${f2py_module_c}"
    COMMAND ${Python_EXECUTABLE}  -m "numpy.f2py"
                    "${fortran_src_file}"
                    -m "${f2py_module_name}"
                    --lower # Important
    DEPENDS "src/foo.f90" # Fortran source
    )

    # Set up target
    Python_add_library(foo MODULE WITH_SOABI
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${f2py_module_c}" # Generated
    "${F2PY_INCLUDE_DIR}/fortranobject.c" # From NumPy
    "${fortran_src_file}" # Fortran source(s) #"foo-f2pywrappers2.f90"
    )

    # Depend on sources
    target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE Python::NumPy)
    add_dependencies(foo genpyf)
    target_include_directories(foo PRIVATE "${F2PY_INCLUDE_DIR}")
endif(PYTHON_F2PY)
```

Inside my building directory I run

```
cmake -Wno-dev -DPYTHON_F2PY=1 ..
```

to generate the project, followed by

```
make -j10
```

to build it.

Among others I get the following files:

- `foo.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` - the shared library that I can load in Python
- `foo-f2pywrappers.f` - an empty Fortran file
- `foo-f2pywrappers2.f90` - Fortran file containing some wrapper code

  ```
  !     -*- f90 -*-
  !     This file is autogenerated with f2py (version:1.26.4)
  !     It contains Fortran 90 wrappers to fortran functions.
  subroutine f2pywrapfoo (foof2pywrap, a, f2py_a_d0, f2py_a_d1)
   integer f2py_a_d0
   integer f2py_a_d1
   real(kind=8) a(f2py_a_d0,f2py_a_d1)
   complex(kind=8) foof2pywrap(size(a, 1),size(a, 2))
   interface
     function foo(a) result (b) 
       real(kind=8), intent(in),dimension(:,:) :: a
       complex(kind=8), dimension(size(a,1),size(a,2)) :: b
     end function foo
   end interface
   foof2pywrap = foo(a)
  end
  ```
- `foomodule.c` - the C code generated for my module that will is used to build shared the library

The error message

```
Python 3.12.0 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Oct  3 2023, 08:43:22) [GCC 12.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/.../myproject/build/foo.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: f2pywrapfoo_
```

points as `f2pywrapfoo_`. As you can see above, the `foo-f2pywrappers2.f90` file contains the function (albeit without the `_` suffix).

What I did is to add that wrapper to the list of Fortran source files

```
# Set up target
Python_add_library(foo MODULE WITH_SOABI
"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${f2py_module_c}" # Generated
"${F2PY_INCLUDE_DIR}/fortranobject.c" # From NumPy
"${fortran_src_file}" "foo-f2pywrappers2.f90" # Fortran source(s)
)
```

I run CMake and `make` again. When I repeat the steps for importing the module, now it works:

```
Python 3.12.0 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Oct  3 2023, 08:43:22) [GCC 12.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from foo import foo
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]], order='F')
>>> foo(a)
array([[ 0.54030231+0.84147098j, -0.41614684+0.90929743j,
        -0.9899925 +0.14112001j, -0.65364362-0.7568025j ],
       [ 0.28366219-0.95892427j,  0.96017029-0.2794155j ,
         0.75390225+0.6569866j , -0.14550003+0.98935825j]])
```

The problem is that `foo-f2pywrappers2.f90` is not available during the first run of CMake and `make`. It is created only after `make` is executed. So I cannot really add it as a dependency for the library building stage in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Any ideas what to change in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple `Makefile`:

```
f2py_module_name = foo

all: foo.pyf foo.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

clean:
    rm -f *.pyf *.so *wrappers* *module.c

foo.pyf: src/foo.f90
    f2py -m $(f2py_module_name) $< -h $@ --overwrite-signature

foo.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: src/foo.f90
    f2py -m $(f2py_module_name) -c $<

foo-f2pywrappers.f foomodule.c foo-f2pywrappers2.f90: src/foo.f90
    f2py -m $(f2py_module_name) $< --lower

test:
    python3 test.py
```

Alternatively, a `CMakeLists.txt` might look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(foo_f2py)

find_package(Python 3.12 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development.Module NumPy)

set(f2py_module_name foo)

add_custom_target(generate_foo_pyf
    COMMAND f2py -m ${f2py_module_name} src/foo.f90 -h foo.pyf --overwrite-signature
    COMMENT "Generate foo.pyf."
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    VERBATIM
)

add_custom_target(generate_foo_so
    COMMAND f2py -m ${f2py_module_name} -c src/foo.f90
    COMMENT "Generate foo.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so."
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    VERBATIM
)

add_custom_target(clean_files
    COMMAND rm -f *.pyf *.so *wrappers* *module.c
    COMMENT "Clean files."
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    VERBATIM
)

add_custom_target(run_tests
    COMMAND python3 test.py
    COMMENT "Run test."
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    VERBATIM
)

add_dependencies(generate_foo_so generate_foo_pyf)

# Set default target.
add_custom_target(default_target ALL DEPENDS generate_foo_so)
```

To build:

```bash
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
# Return to directory containing built package.
cd ..
```

Test using Docker (see screenshot below). Of course, you don't need to use Docker and can just build/run this on your localhost. If you don't have Python 3.12 then you can drop the `find_package()` from `CMakeLists.txt` and all should still be well.

To evaluate this approach with your version of Python (3.12.0) I made a little Docker image.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.12.0

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -y -qq cmake gfortran

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN rm -rf build && \
    mkdir build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake .. && \
    # make
    true
```

`requirements.txt`

```
numpy==1.26.4
meson==1.3.2
ninja==1.11.1.1
```

[image]